# is there a way to run exe file automatically in the tray

Tags: windows-7, command-line, notification-area

I do not like that some of my apps which are running in background constantly are wasting space in my taskbar. I would like to move them to a tray.

Is there a way to run the exe file in the tray?

I assume that there might be some parameter, I can add here:
[image]

Comment: actually I am looking for a solution without additional software. But still thanks

Comment: What you want requires additional software

Comment: There are no generic parameters that all EXEs use, be it for this or anything else. Unless the program you're using supports this (you didn't even bother mentioning what it is), you need a third party program.